# Why do Data Services use the Servlet Ports as opposed to NIO/PT - WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I've installed Dss 3.2.2 features onto Esb4.8.1.

When I create a proxy service the Service endpoints are as expected e.g

```
http://[ip]:8280/services/[proxy_service_name]
```

But when I create a dataservice , the service endpoints also show the same(NIO) port , contrary to the expected (mgmt) port :

```
http://[ip]:8280/services/[data_service_name]
```

But it should  be

```
http://[ip]:9763/services/[data_service_name]
```

If I send a json post request to the 8280 for a dataservice , it does not receive any params :

```
"current_params": "{}"
```

Sending it to 9763 it reads my params:

```
"current_params": "{no=xxx, dump_size=10}"
```

Is there a config/way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using try-it tool shipped with WSO2 ESB by default. Let me explain what it the reason for this problem. WSO2 ESB exposes two HTTP ports (i.e NIO port which is 8280 and servlet port which is 9763) and when dataservice features are installed, data services are also exposed via both ports. By default ESB try-it uses NIO port(8280). The issue is ESB try-it tool does not handle invoking data service via NIO transport. It drops the parameters passed. That is why the current_params is empty. This is a known [issue](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4052) and will be fixed in a future release. As a workaround you can either use servlet port to invoke dataservice or any other soap client such as SoapUI.

Thanks

Comment: I'm testing via SOAPui , even when sending the request via SOAPui to 8280  , it doesns't accept the params! I understand the sending to 9443 makes it work, its just Im implementing a production esb/dss and would like the correct urls to be dislpayed on the console.